# Trouble with OUTER JOIN and multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL, which works:

```
SELECT QuizFamilies.ID, QuizFamilies.Title
FROM QuizFamilies
LEFT OUTER JOIN Images ON QuizFamilies.ID = Images.ID
```

Now, I need to add an additional table (ImageData) to the outer join. (where Images.ID = ImageData.ID) in order to retrieve the column I need from it: ImagesData.Uri

I've tried all sorts of inner and outer combinations, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another join:

```
SELECT QuizFamilies.ID, QuizFamilies.Title, ImageData.URI
FROM QuizFamilies
LEFT OUTER JOIN Images ON QuizFamilies.ID = Images.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ImageData on ImageData.ID = Images.ID
```

Comment: No problem! FYI you can mark this as the "accepted" answer by clicking the checkbox beside it.